# How can I repeat appending a semicolon each line in vi?

Tags: vi, repeat

I tend to abuse the repeating command or dot (.) in vi. I keep forgetting how I could repeat a command over a range of lines. So, I just create a question with my own answer to it.

Say, I have two lines of code.

```
int a
int b
int c
```

I want to append each line with a semicolon to have the following two lines:

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that the cursor is at the 1st column in the 1st line. Then, I could type:

```
A;[ESC]j.j.
```

Another way is to type:

```
A;[ESC]jVj:normal.
```

This allows me to avoid repeatedly typing j.j.j.j.......

Answer (score 0):

You could also do

```
:%s/$/;/
```

which would change the end-of-line character (represented by the '$') to a semi-colon.  If you wanted to restrict this to a range of of lines, you could do

```
:<n>,<m>s/$/;/
```

where *<n>*, and *<m>* are the respective line numbers in the file.

Comment: Thank you for an alternative way.